# forEach() method is only displaying 1 entry, how to get them all to display?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I'm Trying to get firebase to create a table based of each entry from firebase. Its Console logging all the keys correctly but name and cars_sold is [object Object]. Its something simple but Im hitting a wall with it.

```
salespersonRef.once('value') 
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var key = childSnapshot.key;
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
    console.log('Key: ' + key);
    console.log('Data:' + childData);
        $('#salesperson_tbody').append(`
        <tr>
            <td>${$("#name-display").text(childData.name)}</td>
            <td>${$("#cars_sold-display").text(childData.cars_sold)}</td>
        </tr>
    `);
  });
});
```

It console logs the Keys but not the Data and the table also just says [object Object]. It created the right amount of rows, just not showing any of the data.
If I `console.log(childData.name)` then it works but the appending still just displays [object Object].

Comment: I'm guessing `childData.name` is an object. What _exactly_ does the `console.log` show? Better yet, what will `console.log(childData)` show?

Comment: @mbojko console.log(childData) replied with [object Object]

Comment: @mbojko `console.log(childData.name)` replies with everyones name's.